# R function returning data frame (extra column)

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am a beginner to R programming( using it for data analysis)

I have following data. (trimmed version)

```
state   storeid sales
CA  1   40,000  
CA  2   44,000  
CA  3   38000   
MN  1   26000   
MN  2   25500
```

I need a function which return the top/low performing stores.

I wrote the following function.

```
storeinfo<-function(num="top") {

  df<-read.csv("store.csv")

  bestVal <- 1;
  if (!missing(num)) {
    if(is.numeric(num)){
      bestVal =  as.numeric(num);
    }
    if(num=="top"){
      bestVal <-1
    }
    if ( num=="poor"){
      bestVal<-0
    }
  }
  print(bestVal)
    data2<-subset(df[,c(1,2,3)])
    data2<-data2[order(as.numeric( data2$sales), data2$storeid,na.last=TRUE,decreasing=TRUE), ]
    idx<-tapply(1:NROW(data2),data2$state,"[",bestVal)
    idx1<-tapply(1:NROW(data2),data2$state,"[",1)

    return (data.frame(data2[idx1,1],data2[idx,2:3]))

}
```

when i am executing above function, i am seeing the following

```
> head(storeinfo(1))
[1] 1
  data2.idx1..1. storeid  sales
2             CA       2 44,000
4             MN       1  26000
```

a) How to suppress the first column 2,4 etc?(indexes)
b) How to find stores whose sales are low?
c) How to set different column names to returned data frame.

Comment: The first column isn't one; these are your data.frame's row names. You could do `rownames(yourobject) <- NULL` if you want to replace them with 1, 2, 3, etc. You can also change the columns names using `colnames(yourobject) <- c("state", "storeid", "sales")`. The rest is too confusing for me. In particular,  you did not define what you mean by a "store" with respect to `state` and `storeid`.

Comment: retdf<-data.frame(data2[idx1,1],data2[idx,2:3])
retdf.rownames<-NULL AFter this, i am seeing row names in the output.

Comment: retdf<-data.frame(data2[idx1,1],data2[idx,2:3],row.names = NULL) return(retdf)   however, i am seeing row names in the output.

Comment: It should be `rownames(retdf) <- NULL`. You will still see a column of row indices (1, 2, 3, etc.) as the data.frame gets printed though, because that's how R does it. You should not worry too much about it though. For example, were you to write the final data.frame to a file, you can select to include row names or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
min_max_sales = c(which.min(df$sales), which.max(df$sales)) # return row numbers
df[min_max_sales,]
```

UPDATE.

If you need to sort the data frame and get a store with the nth best sales, here is a better approach using the `plyr` package

```
plyr::arrange(df, sales)[n,]
```

Comment: I will try. I have need to find, 2ed best, 3ed best stores etc. This is the reason, I was passing "num" param to function.

Comment: do you just need to sort by sales? In that case you can install the `plyr` package and do `arrange(df, sales)`. This will give you a dataframe sorted by sales and you can extract 1st, 2nd or 3rd best stores.